# makeDelegate function not working

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, delegates

For the question that spawned this one;

- [Multiple variadic templated delegate system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15222638/multiple-variadic-templated-delegate-system)

I've got the following function;

```
template<typename... Arguments, typename... Params> 
Runnable<Params...>* makeRunnable(void (*FunctionType)(Arguments..., Params...), Arguments... args)
{
    return new FunctionDelegate<Arguments..., Params...>(FunctionType, makeTuple(args...));
}
```

Which I'd like to adapt to the solution given by 'ForEveR', in the previous question, I've tried without any luck.

```
template<typename... Arguments, typename... Params> 
Runnable<Params...>* makeRunnable(void (*FunctionType)(tuple<Arguments...>, tuple<Params...>), tuple<Arguments...> args)
{
    return new FunctionDelegate<tuple<Arguments...>, tuple<Params...>>(FunctionType, args);
}
```

Which yields the error;

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘makeRunnable(void (&)(tuple<int, int>, tuple<int>), tuple<int, int>)’
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to fix it myself;

```
// Create a function delegate as runnable
template<typename... Arguments, typename... Params> 
Runnable<Params...>* makeRunnable(void (*FunctionType)(tuple<Arguments...>, tuple<Params...>), Arguments... args)
{
    return new FunctionDelegate<tuple<Arguments...>, tuple<Params...>>(FunctionType, makeTuple(args...));
}
```